# How to correct badly written emails?

Tags: python, string, email, autocorrect

I am trying to correct badly written emails contained in a list, by searching differences in the most common domains. E.g: hotmal.com to hotmail.com.
The thing is, there are tons of variations to one single domain. It would be extremly helpful if someone knew of an algorithm in python that can work as an autocorrect for email domains. Or if this is too complex of a problem for a few lines of code.

Comment: check this out, https://github.com/mattalcock/blog/blob/master/2012/12/5/python-spell-checker.rst

Comment: you'll probably have the best luck with some kind of "fuzzy matching" algo, but this isn't really an SO question

Comment: Look up Levenshtein disatance or edit distance. It may help to have a white list of valid emails and do an edit distance check. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check *Levenshtein distance* starting at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
It is commonly used for auto-correct

Comment: I ended up making an algorithm based on this. Works wonders, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What if...you search for keywords in the domain. Like for hotmail.com, you can search for hot, or something similar. Also, like the @user10817019 wrote, you can combine it with searching for the first and last letters of the domain.

Answer (score -1):

Write a small script in your preferred language that takes domains that start with h and end with l, and replace the entire string with hotmail so it fixes everything in between. Search for mai if they forgot the L. I had to do this the other day in vb.net so check my lists twice and correct bad data.

Comment: So this is going to replace *homedeal.com* with *hotmail.com*. But it does not detect that *hotmali.com* should be *hotmail.com*? I think the OP is looking for something else.